# Difference between intervals

Tags: real-analysis

What are the differences between all kinds of intervals and how many are there?

I know what a compact interval is, it is just $[a,b]$ with $a\leq b$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}.$ What exactly is a closed interval? And is there any other kinds of intervals like open,etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$ we have

$$\begin{align}[a,b]&= \{x \in \mathbb{R}; a \leq x \leq b\}
\\(a,b)&= \{x\in \mathbb{R}; a < x<b\}\\
[a,b)&= \{x\in \mathbb{R}; a < x \leq b\}\\
(a,b]&=\{x\in \mathbb{R}; a \leq x<b\}\\
(-\infty,b]&=\{x\in \mathbb{R}; x \leq b\}\\
(-\infty,b) &= \{x\in \mathbb{R}; x < b\}\\
[a,+\infty)&=\{x\in \mathbb{R}; a \leq x\}\\
(a,+\infty)&=\{x\in \mathbb{R}; a < x\}\\
(-\infty, + \infty) &= \mathbb{R}\end{align}$$

$[a,b]$ is closed, $(a,b)$ is open, $[a,b)$ and variations are neither.

A closed set means that every point is a limit of some sequence of points in the set.

Comment: bonus: $(-\infty, b]$, $[a,\infty)$ and $\Bbb R$ are closed as well.